# Resetting for cold boot emulation engine failed Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, android-emulator, emulation

I've tried a lot of suggestions how to fix it but they all doesn't work

Comment: Can you flush out your question a bit?  What are you talking about?  How does it fail?  What suggestions did you try?  How did they not work?  This is really a non-question (note the absence of a question mark).

Comment: You can check this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74608532/emulator-starts-and-shuts-down-within-seconds/74917242#74917242:~:text=You%20can%20try,repair%20to%20complete.)