# emulator starts and shuts down within seconds

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator

In Visual Studio 2022, when I start the emulator from Android Device Manager, the emulator starts and shuts down within seconds. shows this message `No Android SDK instance matching the 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk' path`
I have tried many things, but the problem is still there.

I'm using `Galaxy Nexus - API 31(Android 12.0 - API 31)`

OUTPUT

```
Successfully started Broker in-process
Connecting to Local Broker...
Successfully connected to Local Broker
Starting IDB Local Agent...
Successfully started IDB Local Agent
Checking xma 17.4.0.312 installation...
SetSelectedDeviceAsync BEST Simulator
No Android SDK instance matching the 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk' path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

1. Make sure you have turn Windows features on for “Hyper-V” and “Windows Hypervisor Platform”.
   Note: if you have installed “Intel Hardwar Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)” from VS installer “Individual components”, you don’t have to turn Windows features on for “Hyper-V” and “Windows Hypervisor Platform”.
2. Please try to remove the system image directory `“C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-28(what you have created)\google_apis_playstore\x86”`
3. Please try to clean the cache in `“C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\xamarin-android-sdk”`
4. Go to Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager… > to check if there is an “SDK needs repair” message pop up, if the message pups up, click “Repair” button, and waiting for the repair to complete.