# VS 2022 can't start Android Emulator

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

I just updated my Visual Studio from 2019 to 2022. I encountered no problems when I am using the 2019 version, the emulators are launching and working well. But ever since I installed 2022, the emulators starts for a while then close immediately.

Here are additional details:
**Output Window**

```
Starting emulator pixel_5_-_api_33 ...
1>Waiting for emulator to be ready...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -netfast -accel on -avd pixel_5_-_api_33 -prop monodroid.avdname=pixel_5_-_api_33
Emulator pixel_5_-_api_33 was stopped.
1>Starting deployment to pixel_5_-_api_33 ...
1>Starting emulator pixel_5_-_api_33 ...
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -netfast -accel on -avd pixel_5_-_api_33 -prop monodroid.avdname=pixel_5_-_api_33
1>Emulator pixel_5_-_api_33 was stopped.
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Elapsed 00:50.443 ==========
```

Here's a screenshot of the emulator starting, then closes immediately:

[image]

What can I do to fix this?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Did you try to create a new emulator or delete this one and reinstall it?

Comment: Yes, I've tried but still get the same results

Comment: You can check the official document about the [Android emulator troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/troubleshooting?pivots=windows), when I install the VS 2022, the emulator can work well.

Comment: I created and manage to run an emulator, but it is in Pixel 2 - Android 9 (API 28), which is what I use in 2019.

Comment: If the Pixel 2 - Android 9 (API 28) can work, the others should also work. You can check the difference between this one and the other. Such as did you add the google api when you created it.

Comment: You can try this. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74608532/emulator-starts-and-shuts-down-within-seconds/74917242#74917242) @KLeo

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and here is the solution i found :
Check if Windows Hypervisor Platform is enabled. To do that open **Windows Features** tool executing choosing Turn Windows features on or off start option and verify if **Hyper-V** and **Windows Hypervisor Platform** are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

"I had the same problem. The solution for me was to install Android Studio, then run the build. After everything finished, I tried running it again in Visual Studio 2022, and it worked. I got the same screen again, but it remained active. When I clicked "dismiss", everything worked as it should. I hope this helps you too."

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have enough disk space.
Run this command from your **Output window** manually: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE ...`
And it will show you the exact error. Something like `ERROR   | Not enough space to create userdata partition.`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, to fix it create a new instance of an Android device but don't edit it afterwards.
Somehow that causes the emulator to stop working with visual studio.

[image]